# How can I get rid of dashes in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

How can I get rid of this dashes in Visual Studio?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an option in `Edit -> Advanced -> View White Space`.  Turn that option off.

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will toggle the option.

Comment: I've been looking for this feature forever - I always wondered why Notepad++ had it, and VS "didn't."  I was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to `Go to Edit -> Advanced and uncheck "View whitespace"`.

Short cut is <kbd>CTRL+E</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>